# Needing Excel help on deleting with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a way to have my Excel delete everything with an "N" in the second column, but ALSO delete all of the instances in column one where there is a duplicate number that contains an "N" at some point.

I would want the entire row of the first two numbers deleted because they both had an "N". I would also want both instances of 8573217 deleted because one of them contained an "N".

Is there a way to do this with a formula or a macro?

[image: Excel]

Comment: What do you mean by "delete all of the instances in column one" in some circumstances. What "instance" has to mean in your case? Do you find a fancy word for a cell, or is it something I miss?

Comment: Is my next understanding/supposition correct? If there is an "N" in a cell of second column, that **entire row will be deleted"", but the value of the cell in column "A:A" on that deleted row should be memorized prior to delition. Then, looking in column A:A for all values being the same with memorized cell and also **delete that rows where such occurrences appear**. Would be that correct? If not, can you better elaborate your need?

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Criteria Formula Simplified

You can use the Advanced Filter and copy/to another location
For example (with the first table data entry in `Column1` in cell `A7`)

**Criteria Formula:**

```
=COUNTIFS(Table5[Column1],A7,Table5[Column2],"N")=0
```

**Advanced Filter Dialog**

[image]

**Implemented**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to create a new column, which enters `N` for each value where there is such an entry, having a `N`, this can be achieved using a `countifs()` formula.
Then, create a macro which removes all rows having `N` in that new column.

Comment: But, such a column already exists. Besides its existence witch is clear, do you understand anything else from the 'interesting description' of the need?